# Octave FWHM calculation

Tags: octave, distribution, gaussian

I am having some problem about calculating the FWHM of my data. Because the "fwhm" function in signal package results in a 100 times bigger value than i expected to get.

What i did is that,

Depending on the gaussian distribution function (you can find it on wikipedia) I produced some data. In this function you can give a specific sigma (RMS) value (FWHM=sigma*2.355). Here is that the script I wrote to understand the situation

```
x=10:0.01:40;
x0=25;
sigma=0.25;
y=(1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((x-x0).^2)/(2*sigma^2));
z=fwhm(y)/2.355;
plot(x,y)
```

when I compared the results the output of "fwhm" function (24.999) is 100 times bigger than the one I used (0.25) in the function.

If you have any idea it will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your z is 100 times bigger because your steps in x are 1/100 (0.01). If you use fwhm(y) it is expected that the stepsize in x is 1. If not you have to specify that.

In your case you should do:

```
z=fwhm(x, y)/2.355
z =  0.24999
```

which matches your sigma